# Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010 Requires .NET 4.0

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, setup-project

When setting up a [`Setup Project`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c.aspx) in Visual Studio 2010 and even to I removing all the prerequistes `.NET 4.0` is still *required* on the computer that runs the Installation. Deploying with [`ClickOnce`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx) works but is not an option, but at least it doesn't ask for .NET 4.0.

**Is there a way to create a Setup Project in Visual Studio 2010 that doesn't require .NET 4.0 on installation?**

---

**Edit**

This is one of the test configurations i've tested

[image]

And this is what it looks like when I run setup.exe or the .msi

[image]

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Right click on the setup project in the solution explorer -> View -> Launch Conditions and set the appropriate .NET framework version:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, that works like a charm! Thanks A Lot! I almost though I had to install an older version of visual stuido ;)

Comment: superb, dont know why microsoft products does this job automatically.

Comment: what if i want to give my hard disk path as install url ?